# Video transitions in iOS - blur, zoom etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, core-animation

I am working on a video editing app for iOS, I am currently struggling to add smooth transitions to the app.

For example:
[image: zoom transition]

My video is composited using `AVMutableVideoComposition` and `AVAssetTrack`.
I tried manually coding the transitions using `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` and `CAKeyframeAnimation` to animate `CATransform3D`:

```
// The values are arbitrary for simplicity
let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
animation.duration=0.35
animation.values = [
                NSValue(caTransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)),
                NSValue(caTransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(2, 2, 2)),
                NSValue(caTransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(3, 3, 3)),
                NSValue(caTransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(4, 4, 4)),
                NSValue(caTransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(5, 5, 5)),
                NSValue(caTransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(4, 4, 4)),
                NSValue(caTransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(3, 3, 3)),
                NSValue(caTransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(2, 2, 2)),
                NSValue(caTransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1))]

            animation.keyTimes = [0, 0.125, 0.250, 0.375 etc...]
            animation.beginTime = transitionStartTime
            videoLayer.add(animation, forKey:"transform")
```

This works as a very naive zoom transition but it's missing the distortion/warping/blur animations etc...
The dream is to make it like the gif above which I see 2 paths:
 **1. I can easily do those transitions in Adobe After Effects(check gif below), any ideas how can I integrate that into iOS? Perhaps you got some ideas.

 2. Figure out how to manually animate blur, distortion & warping of a video in Swift, I checked `CIFilter` which looked good but it only supports Mac OS. I am considering [GPUImage3](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage3) now. Any ideas?**
[image: adobe after effects zoom transition]

Comment: `CIFilter` has been available on iOS since iOS 5.0

Comment: @beyowulf it is not available to be used as filters to `CALayers` etc... on iOS